# Domain registered on aws, how to create my domain email

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-server

I have been looking online for a tutorial on how to set up an email address @mydomain for a domain I registered on aws.

I have already set up an aws instance running my app, and an Amazon SES. Also, I have verified my domain so that I can send emails from it.

Now, I understand how to send emails, but I do not understand how to set up an email with the domain of my ec2 instance. Do I have to set up a mail server on my ec2 instance? If yes, how do I do that?

I apologize if there is already an answer to this question but I really could not find anything clear online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you need a place to host/receive your emails, there are a few managed services, or a couple of ways to host them your self.

About managed services, check out

- https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/
- https://gsuite.google.com/products/gmail/
- https://products.office.com/en/business/office-365-business-email-and-shared-calendar-services

Also, check out DigitalOceans article about why you may not want to host your own email here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server

Comment: No problem, I have bin down the road with self-hosted many times before... Never again ☺️